# 3G mobile data carrier shows different website

Tags: android, mobile, web, 3g

I made a responsive website for someone, and after I launched it online, I figured out this thing.

On mobile devices, when accessing the website, it shows a different website, but only on 3G/4G. If the mobile is connected to a wireless device, it shows the correct website.Both on android & ios.

How can I resolve it?

This is the website I get. And isn`t what is on the ftp server.

[image]

Comment: what does it happen if you access that site on a computer browser using `m.` instead of `www.`?

Comment: @cosmincalistru Still the same website as in the image. You think that on 3G it redirects automatically to m.mysite.ro and showing the mobile version?

Should I make a subdomain called m. and redirect it to current domain?

Comment: I really don't know how to solve this but at least now you now the cause.